# How does HTML5 deal with being able to run .NET managed code like Silverlight does?

Tags: .net, silverlight, html

Ok I am in the infancy stages of understanding HTML5 so bear with me. I understand HTML5 is the obvious future for video, streaming, interactivity, etc. no question. But one of the big pluses for Silverlight (since version 2) is the ability to run .NET Managed code on the client. Yes it requires the Silverlight plug-in, but this aside being able to run managed code is a powerful feature. Using WCF to get back to the server is a cinch, so I like this ability and have embedded several Silverlight controls on my ASP.NET pages because of its rich ability.

With all the talk about HTML5 pushing Silverlight aside (even directly or indirectly from MSFT), is HTML5 going to be able to facilitate the running of managed .NET code client-side from the web like Silverlight does?

Thanks!

Comment: Javascript should be enough for everyone. Choice of programming language? Static typing? Who needs that? Only those that are too incompetent to use JS want that.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: the issue isn't the choice, its the accuracy.  See the StackOverflow blogs where they struggled to ensure that the server side MarkDown processor was creating the EXACT same html output as the Client side version.  being able to run the same code both server and client side has huge benefits, regardless of the language used.  (which is why there is actually an implementation of JS for the server side)

Comment: "With all the talk about HTML5 pushing Silverlight aside".  Really?  First I've ever heard about such a notion.

Comment: @subt13 - [Just a few days ago Microsoft announced Windows 8 apps would be HTML5/JavaScript.](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/features/2011/jun11/06-01corporatenews.aspx) Some people have been nervous.

Comment: @Richard - Thanks for the link.  Seems like a step backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML will have no facility specifically for running Microsoft executable code in the foreseeable future, no.  In order to run .NET code from within the browser, either a plugin is required (such as with Silverlight) or the browser would have to call a local executable (which itself requires something beyond standard HTML/JavaScript, for security reasons).

The point is that HTML/CSS/JavaScript are universally supported out of the box.  So instead of writing code that requires the user to install a plugin (.NET code, Flash code, etc.), you write code that runs in a standard browser (JavaScript, HTML, etc.).

You can still run .NET code just fine on the server, and can communicate with the server via AJAX very easily.  But for client-side code the push in this particular scenario is away from proprietary technology with plugins to standard technology that's supported by default.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.  It will be using JavaScript in an accelerated way to negate the need (arguably) for a plugin such as SilverLight or Flash

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish a similar effect using HTML/Javascript/AJAX, without the need for proprietary technology and plugins. In the place of your imbedded Silverlight controls, you will be able to provide cross-browser, cross-platform, standards-oriented code and be able to "manage" it via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

In .NET, managed code is compiled to the [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language). On the other hand, standard web technologies tend stand on the shoulders of text:

- HTML is text
- XML is text
- CSS is text
- ECMAScript is text

So its very unlikely that HTML5 will support .NET managed code.

Comment: I know we are splitting hairs here, but I believe JavaScript IS managed code.

Comment: If we're splitting hairs, there's no way JS is managed code since it doesn't run on the CLR.

Comment: @Marc, since when is the CLR a requirement to be Managed code?  Java is managed and it sure as heck doesn't run on the CLR. Managed typically means there is some sort of automatic memory management, which JavaScript absolutely has.

Comment: @Neil N - In general you might be right, but this question is specifically tagged [.net] and in .NET "managed code" has kind of a specific meaning... no?

Comment: I guess the answer (not the question) should be clarified to be .Net Managed code.

Comment: Yep to clarify I *did* mean .NET Managed code. Sorry if there was any ambiguity there.